# How fix No definition found for class:'android.content.Context'. Check your definitions! in KoinTest

Tags: android, koin

In my KoinTest extends

```
@Before
    fun setUp() {
        startKoin { modules(KoinStarter.getModules()) }
    }

@Test
fun `should inject my components`() {
    val settingsStore: SettingsStore = get()
    assertNotNull(settingsStore)
}
```

I get error No definition found for class:'android.content.Context'. Check your definitions!

But my module located in KoinStarter.getModules()

```
val localDataModule = module {
    factory<Resources> { get<Context>().resources }
    single<SettingsStore> { SettingsStore(get<Context>()) }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the application context in the `androidContext()` method.

Since your question is about testing specifically, in my case I had to pass application context via ApplicationProvider:

```
startKoin {
    androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
    .....
}
```

Don't forget to add the androidx dependency:

`testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'`

Comment: Could you try instead of `get<Context>()` to use `androidContext()`

Comment: New error:

Can't resolve Context instance. Please use androidContext() function in your KoinApplication configuration.

Comment: Have you added `androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())` inside the `startKoin{}` block in your test class?